# Should triggers only be used for something that's not possible with SQL?

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, database-design, triggers

I'm currently writing an application that uses SQLite.  SQLite doesn't have the `ON UPDATE` function for timestamps so I wrote my first trigger for it.  Then I wrote a trigger to add the current timestamp on the modified and created fields on an insert.

The problem came when I went and deleted the setting of the modified/created fields for the insert. I felt like I was hiding something from developers that might see my code in the future. It could be a source of confusion.

How will they know that the sql is coming from a trigger. Should I comment it? Is it bad practice?

Answer (score 2):

As a rule of thumb, triggers are meant to implement SQL functional rules, such as inclusions, exclusions, partitions etc. 
This kind of thing belongs to the model and should be implemented as triggers whenever it is possible. It has to be delivered with the database **otherwise the model would be broken**.

Regarding to your case, it is more a hack than anything. If you can't do differently, do it and then add a comment like you said. But it should remain an exception.

Keep in mind that almost everything a trigger is doing could be done at the application layer (whichever you want)

Answer (score 1):

Good observation. There are some things only triggers can do. However I suggest that if there is any alternative to using a trigger then use the alternative. I'm not familiar with SQLite, but in any other database I would use a DEFAULT rather than a trigger to timestamp a new record. To capture updated date I would enclose this in a stored procedure, or whatever database side logic you have (kind of what RandomUs1r suggested). I might consider a trigger but only for very basic operations.

You are correct that triggers can be confusing and difficult to debug.

Answer (score 1):

"I felt like I was hiding something from developers..." - this is a very good point.  I've came across many developers who use @@Identity and were genuinely shocked that if somebody put a trigger on the table which inserted another row, they'd end up with the wrong identity.  (As opposed to SCOPE_IDENTITY() - I know these are sql server specific, but that's pretty much all I know...)

It is hidden - other than documentation I'm not sure you can make it more visible either.

Which is why many avoid them where possible - I guess if there's no easy way around using them in some cases then as long as its well documented, etc.  I think like cursors, although scorned by many they can be very powerful and useful...but if they can be avoided probably for the best.

Answer (score 0):

On the code that modifies the record, to get the current timestamp... in SQLLite, try:

```
DATETIME('NOW')
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: what, that triggers are a hack for what he's trying to do, others have mentioned this? I've provided what he needs to put into the statements that are actually modifying the records and need to update the timestamp.